# Is it possible to prove $\int _\gamma f \, dz \ne 0$ with Green's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\Bbb C$, and let $f : U \to \Bbb C$ be an analytic function. Let $\gamma$ be a
closed curve in $U$. Prove or disprove that $\int _\gamma f\, dz =0$.

I started with Green's Theorem: Let $z=x+iy$ and let $\Omega$ be the interior of $\gamma$. We have,

$$\int _\gamma f(z) \, dz = i \iint_\Omega \left ( \frac {\partial f}{\partial x} +  i \frac {\partial f}{\partial y}\right )$$

Suppose $U$ not simply connected such that there exists a subset of $\Omega$, $ \Omega'$, such that $\Omega'$ is not in $U$. In $\Omega'$, $f$ is not defined. This is where I am stuck. Since $f$ is not defined does it disprove the statement or can I just not use Green's Theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disprove a statement which claims something is always true, all you need to do is construct a counter example.

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$, a function that is analytic on $U=C-\{0\}$, an open set. Let $\gamma$ be the unit circle (radius $1$ center at $0$, parametrize by $e^{i\theta}$, $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$). $$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z} \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{e^{i\theta}}ie^{i\theta} \, d\theta=2\pi i\neq 0.$$

Therefore the statement is false.